# Error in installation in windows service in VS2005

Tags: c#, windows-services

Windows Service installation error "The installer was interrupted before application could be installed.You need to restart the installer to try again." I am using VS2005

Answer (score 0):

Try installing with logging.

Example:

```
msiexec /i <path to msi file> /l*vx D:\YourService.log
```

Comment: I am trying with adding setup project.It will be help full if you answer using this....